# Guava cache eviction policy

Tags: guava

I tried guava cache recently and was surprised by eviction policy. Although the cache is clearly stated as an lru in docs, but it isn't defacto. For me evictions looks random as my test shows. (the test is to add 100 etnries, get 100 entries, pot different 100 entries, check eviction order) I'd not like to detect some unexpected evictions in runtime. Could you please provide some background behind eviction policy for a size limited Cache. How can i force guava cache to evict like LHM does?

Answer (score 21):

Guava caches are *segmented* into `concurrencyLevel` different hash tables to allow multiple concurrent reads and writes.  The default `concurrencyLevel` is 4.  Basically, if your `maximumSize` is set to `100`, then that actually only results in each of the four segments getting a `maximumSize` of 25.  This is why the `maximumSize` documentation states:

> Note that the cache may evict an entry before this limit is exceeded. As the cache size grows close to the maximum, the cache evicts entries that are less likely to be used again.

So if by chance, there were 30 entries that went into one particular segment, then 5 of those entries will get evicted.

The only way to get global least-recently-accessed eviction for a `Cache` is to turn off concurrency entirely by setting `concurrencyLevel(1)`.  Even then, the documentation does not make any *guarantees* on the eviction order of elements, and you should not depend on it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer Louis. For me it was unclear how to treat that documentation statement. So, less concurrencyLevel = more LRU. But i still confused with segment level eviction. am i right if a segment becomes full say > 25 (100/4) in my case, eviction will start? or it will evict only at ~maxSize but will evict a segment level lru entry?

Comment: If a segment goes above 25 entries, it will evict the least-recently-used entry _in that segment._

Comment: (Basically, each segment operates more or less completely independently, so they can be used concurrently without blocking each other.)

Comment: Louis, is that still true? I remember that being true last year, but I thought that at some point LocalCache got a global eviction queue (or two). Too lazy to read the code again :)

Comment: Looking at the code, it looks like it's still true.  Global eviction queues are expensive!

Comment: Global eviction is not too expensive, as proven in the reference implementation which last I checked outperformed Guava. It was not adopted due to complexities of integrating into the hashtable design used and a desire for simplicity to focus on API/features.